# Creating Java Library(JAR) using Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, jar, android-ndk

I am creating a framework for a media player for Android. Rendering part of the media player is handled by native code written in C++ (OpenGL ES 2.0). Currently, I am able to compile C++ code with help of JNI and it's working (While testing it with a sample Android application).

The goal is to create a .jar file that includes a Renderer.so file which is generated by compiling the C++ code using ndk.

I used this gradle.build of my sample app to configure the ndk build with a custom android.mk file.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
...     
android {
    ...

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set libs as .so's location instead of jniLibs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk
    }

    // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}
```

But while considering the Java library, how can I configure this and compile my native code?

I have no idea how to create a Java Library with .so libs. Is there any way to configure it through gradle?

How can I configure JNI and ndk build settings if I am creating a framework?